# Why we don't normalize the images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I was watching the video from this [stanford course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEoyxE0GP2M) on convolutional neural nets where the professor says (at 28:59) 'we do zero-mean the pixel values in image but we do not normalize the pixel values much because in images, at each location, we already have relatively comparable scale and distribution'. I do not understand what does she mean by 'relatively comparable scale and distribution'?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why he said that. [Image Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) is extremely common in practice!

Say you have an image with pixel values in $[0, 255]$. Besides removing the mean, you also want to divide by either the $(max - min)$ or by the standard deviation. The first step's goal is to reduce the mean of the dataset to zero, while the second's is to scale the pixel values down to a range close to $[-1, 1]$.

Note that all these measures (mean, min, max, std) are calculated on the whole dataset (not on each image individually.

Comment: how do we calculate mean from whole dataset? I mean like do we calculate mean of whole dataset by calculating mean of each image and then add it to the running mean of all images or do we calculate mean by taking in account the spatial location of all images ?

Comment: Just the mean of the pixel intensities of all pixels in the dataset. One way to do is is like you first said.

Comment: it's not extremely common to normalize image inputs. in fact, not normalizing is also pretty common; people usually just scale images to [0, 1] range (e.g., divide the uint8 image by 255).

Comment: @goker scaling the image from [0, 255] to [0, 1] **is** normalization though...

Comment: @Djib2011 you're right; I should have said standardization, which is actually what the question asks about. so I was trying to say that standardization (scaling each pixel individually to std dev 1) is not common.

Comment: just to clarify my comment, what is said in the lecture mentioned in the question is in fact correct; in images, because all features are pixels (which usually have similar distributions), we don't treat each pixel separately when normalizing.

Comment: Well, what you're saying is correct, I must have gotten carried away with the title of the question, which in hindsight is a bit misleading...  I agree the most common practice is to simply scale the inputs to [0, 1] because you don't need to compute any statistics beforehand, though I've also encountered standardization in several occasions. I'd argue that the latter is even more theoretically sound, however is the former is much more convenient and in practice the difference between the two is negligible.